# Creating a sidebar in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Normally, when you create a data-role="page" element with jQuery mobile, it takes over the entire viewing area. For this reason, I don't understand how to create a sidebar. I'd like to emulate the following, but view source doesn't help much:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/lists/index.html

Notice that when you click an item in the list, it turns into a sidebar and shows another list in the main content area. Additionally, if the display is shrunk enough it only displays the main content area. Is there a special feature in jQuery mobile that allows this, or is there a large amount of opaque javascript and CSS behind it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking over the beta Split View syntax you can control the "Sidebar" like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="jqm-home" class="type-home"> 
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <div class="content-secondary"> 
            This would be the sidebar/split view on a tablet, 
            would show up stacked on a mobile device
        </div><!-- end content-secondary -->    

        <div class="content-primary"> 
            This is the main content. 

            If Tablet device this would be to the right of the above content, 
            if mobile this would be below the above content.

        </div><!-- end content-primary -->
    </div><!-- end content -->
</div><!-- end page -->
```

Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/ (right click to view source)

Pertinent CSS: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/_assets/css/jqm-docs.css

A decent ALA article talking about media queries (what they used to do this): http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Comment: Yeah I saw that too, but I don't think that actually is where the sidebar is made. I believe that's the code for splitting up the two separate lists shown in the link you just gave. That's why I don't think "view source" is helpful in this context...it only shows what the root of the demo looks like.

Comment: This actually is how the sidebar is accomplished - take a look at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/_assets/css/jqm-docs.css - which is the extra css for the demo - they are just using media queries to push #content-secondary to the left if there is enough screen real estate.

Comment: I stand corrected, but I'm still confused. When I try to emulate the code above, clicking on any link in the sidebar causes the entire view to be replaced by the new data-role="page" element I linked to. The desired behavior (which the demo has) is to change the main content area and the sidebar remains. How does the linking work?

Comment: Looking closer, it appears as though they are cheating slightly by using a different transition - and the sidebar simply is duplicated on every page as needed. - it looks like they override the transition to either be none on very wide screens, or fade on slightly smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code to a javascript file:

```
function setPositions(){
    var winwidth = $( window ).width()

    if( winwidth >= 750 ){
        $('.content-secondary').css({'float':'left','width':'35%'});
        $('.content-primary').css({'margin-left':'36%'});
    }
    else{
        $('.content-secondary').css({'float':'none','width':'100%'});
        $('.content-primary').css({'margin-left':'0px'});
    }
}


$(function(){
    setDefaultTransition();
    $( window ).bind( "throttledresize", setPositions );
});
```

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to do with JavaScript what should be done with CSS.

Comment: you should do this with CSS media queries instead, please read: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: I prefer using js over media queries ... ... css should **not** be used to handle logic (that's what the media queries are effectively doing) ... that's the job of a scripting language, like js ... ... ...css's job is to hold data (basically a "database" of layout-related values that is "queried" during parsing)